# How to set absolute session timeout in websphere liberty profile?

Tags: websphere-liberty

I need to set absolute session timeout (timeout the session regardless the user is active or not) in websphere liberty profile server for an application?
How do I do that ?  I know inactivity timeout setting. But it is not the requirement, absolute timeout is the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you **JAAS** enable your application, activate the Lightweight Third Party Authentication (LTPA) and set the absolute time, regardless activity.
The default expiration time is 2 hours and is an absolute time, not based on user activities. After the 2 hours, the token expires and the user must log in again to access the resource. **[Liberty: Authentication](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwlp_authentication.html)**

**or**

Just set the global session timeout in liberty to x seconds (which is for inactivity), and in your web application for each communication front it with a filter or something similar that checks the session getCreationTime and invalidate it if it exceeds x seconds. Also some good guide and reading [**here**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1303_lansche/1303_lansche.html)

In this case you will have session invalidity for both inactive and active users.

Comment: Thanks you very much.